# Reading multiple char inputs on one line

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, char

I have ran into a bit of a dilemma, I need to just change my array so that it is read in as one string per line instead of a single character; however when I do so it completely changes my whole program. I can provide more code if needed.

I have tried hasNext and everything else I can think of. I have placed an example of what I mean down below

If the user enters : 2

than the user wants to enter `O,X,O,X` but I want to make it so they can still enter characters but multiple on each line.
I want them to be able to enter `OX` on one line and `OX` on the nextline.

```
package mazeanalyze.java;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author RexABBWJonathan
 */
public class MazeAnalyzeJava {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n][n];
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n+1][n+1];
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n + 1][n + 1];
    System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
                mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
            else {
                mazeValue[i][j] = kbd.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    System.out.println("");
    openfactor(mazeValue, n);
    System.out.println("");
    horizontalPath(mazeValue, n);
    System.out.println(" ");
    verticalPath(mazeValue,n);
    System.out.println(" ");
    //openfactor(mazeValue, n);
    //average(mazeValue,n,totalOpenness);
}
    public static void printMaze(char mazeValue[][]) {
    System.out.println("MAZE");
    for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5c", mazeValue[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}

   public static void horizontalPath(char mazeValue[][], int n) {
    int[] totalRow = new int[n];

    // int horizontalPath=0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (mazeValue[i][j] == 'O') {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (totalRow[i - 1] < count)
                    totalRow[i - 1] = count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (totalRow[i - 1] < count)
            totalRow[i - 1] = count;
        count = 0;
    }
    int biggestRow = totalRow[0];
    // int longestRow=0;
    int finalLongestRow = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        if (biggestRow < totalRow[x]) {
            biggestRow = totalRow[x];
            finalLongestRow = x;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Longest horizontal path row %d length %d", finalLongestRow + 1, biggestRow);
}
public static void verticalPath(char mazeValue[][], int n) {
    int[] totalColumn = new int[n];

    // int horizontalPath=0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue.length; j++){
        for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue[j].length; i++) {

            if (mazeValue[i][j] == 'O') {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (totalColumn[j - 1] < count)
                    totalColumn[j - 1] = count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (totalColumn[j - 1] < count)
            totalColumn[j - 1] = count;
        count = 0;
    }
    int biggestColumn = totalColumn[0];
    // int longestRow=0;
    int finalLongestColumn = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        if (biggestColumn < totalColumn[x]) {
            biggestColumn = totalColumn[x];
            finalLongestColumn = x;
        }
    }
    //System.out.printf("Longest horizontal path row %d length %d", finalLongestColumn + 1, biggestColumn);

   System.out.printf("Longest vertical path column %d length %d", finalLongestColumn + 1, biggestColumn);

}
   public static void openfactor(char[][] mazeValue, int n)
       {
           //double rowAvg=0;
           //double totalRowAvg=0;
       int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n+1][n+1];
       System.out.println("STATISTICS");
       for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
       {  
           double rowAvg=0;
           double totalRowAvg=0;

           for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
          {

              int count=0;
              int openness=0;
              int totalRowOpeness = 0;
              //double rowAvg=0;

               if(mazeValue[i][j]=='X'){
                   count--;
               }

              else 
               {
               //YOU NEED TO VERIFY THAT J IS NOT OUT OF BOUND
               if( j-1>=1)
                    {
               if(mazeValue[i][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                      // System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                    if(i-1>=1 && j-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                     if(i-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                     }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j-1>=1 && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(i-1>=1 && j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
            //}//eND OF iF CONDITION\
            }
            openness = openness +count;
            totalOpenness[i][j] = openness;
            //System.out.println("TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "]  IS " +totalOpenness[i][j]);
            System.out.printf("%5d",totalOpenness[i][j]);
            totalRowOpeness = totalRowOpeness + totalOpenness[i][j];
            rowAvg = (double)totalRowOpeness/(double)n;
            totalRowAvg = totalRowAvg + rowAvg;
         }
        //System.out.println("TOTAL SUM ROW AVERAGE: " +totalRowAvg);
        System.out.printf("%5.1f",totalRowAvg);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for(int j=1; j<=n;j++){
        double ColumnAvg=0;
        double totalColumnAvg=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=n;i++){
            int count=0;
            int openness=0;
            int totalColumnOpeness = 0;

            if(mazeValue[i][j]=='X'){
                   count--;
               }

              else 
               {
               //YOU NEED TO VERIFY THAT J IS NOT OUT OF BOUND
               if( j-1>=1)
                    {
               if(mazeValue[i][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                      // System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                    if(i-1>=1 && j-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                     if(i-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                     }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j-1>=1 && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(i-1>=1 && j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
            //}//eND OF iF CONDITION\
            } 
            openness = openness +count;
            totalOpenness[j][i] = openness;
            //System.out.println("TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [" + j + "]" +"[" + i + "]  IS " +totalOpenness[j][i]);
            totalColumnOpeness = totalColumnOpeness + totalOpenness[j][i];
            ColumnAvg = (double)totalColumnOpeness/(double)n;
            totalColumnAvg = totalColumnAvg + ColumnAvg;
        }
        //System.out.println("TOTAL SUM COLUMN AVERAGE: " +totalColumnAvg);
        System.out.printf("%5.1f",totalColumnAvg);

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `however when I do so it completely changes my whole program` You're going to have to be *a lot* more specific.

Comment: I tried to create a string STR and do mazeValue[i][j] = STR.charAt(j); and it worked but jacked up all my counts and averages through out my program.

Comment: I have updated my code so you can see more. I have no idea how to change this in the correct way.

Comment: OK, if I did understand well, you have to 1/ use readLine() 2/ break the line into char and take N (N being the user enterered value). Are you asking how to perform step 2?

Comment: The counts and averages you mention. Are you referring to the for-loops when creating the maze? If you want to do the String.charAt(x) idea, you just need to create a separate counter, and increment it every time after you get a char. And when you reach the end of the String, have them enter a new one.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, BUT the user will enter a number, that number will be the size of my 2D array (ex : 5 -> array size 5x5) THEN the user enters his path which, BUT the way I have it he can only enter one character at a time and I just found out I need it to be able to reach multiple characters on each line.

Comment: Where would that separate for loop go? could you post a sample?

Comment: String input = "";
  int charPosition = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
    if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
     mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
    else {
     if( input.equals("") || input.length() <= charPosition )
     {
      input = kbd.nextLine();
      charPosition = 0;
     }
     mazeValue[i][j] = input.charAt(charPosition);
     charPosition++;
    }
   }
  }

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to preserve formatting in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are calling "kbd.next().charAt(0);". The issue with this is that .next() gets a string (in your case "oxxox" or something) and then only getting the first char, so everything afterwards is being lost.

I do not know another way with scanner to read in chars. So below is my proposed code for main. What it does is it just calls ".next()" and then iterates through it. Since the counters i and j operate differently than what we want. We need to create a local counter that we manually increment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    // int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n][n];
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n + 1][n + 1];
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n + 1][n + 1];
    System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");

    String input = ""; //Where we store kbd.next()
    int charPosition = 0; //Our manual counter

    for (int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
                mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
            else {
                while( input.equals("") || input.length() <= charPosition )
                {
                    input = kbd.next();
                    charPosition = 0;
                }
                mazeValue[i][j] = input.charAt(charPosition);
                charPosition++;
            }
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    System.out.println("");
    openfactor(mazeValue, n);
    System.out.println("");
    horizontalPath(mazeValue, n);
    System.out.println(" ");
    verticalPath(mazeValue,n);
    System.out.println(" ");
    openfactor(mazeValue, n);
    average(mazeValue,n,totalOpenness);
}
```

Comment: Dude, you have no idea how much you just saved me. I felt like I copromised my whole program by messing that portion up. you are a freaking life SAVERRRRRRRR.

Comment: @FredrickWilliams No problem, glad I could help and I hope you learned something new :)